# How to make SUM function return an integer instead of a string in SQLITE(Sqflite)?

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

Everything is working fine except that my Sum function is returning a weird string, instead of just a number.

Here the function fetching total from a column in Database:

```
  Future getTotal () async {
var dbClient = await db;
var result = await dbClient.rawQuery(
    "SELECT SUM(columnName) FROM tableName");
     return result.toString();
    }
```

`getTotal()` is returning this: `"[{SUM(columnName): 220}]"`

I want it to return just this: `220`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `rawQuery()` returns a `List<Map>`, you will have to use

```
Future getTotal() async {
  var dbClient = await db;
  var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(columnName) FROM $tableScorer");
  int value = result[0]["SUM(columnName)"]; // value = 220
  return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hey, I am new to all this. Can you tell my why my questions are downvoted? 
I try my best to explain the question always. 
I am asking this since i got warning from StackOverflow that i might be blocked due to this.
It will be great if you could guide me

Comment: Its returning null for me instead of '220'.

Comment: Future getMatchRuns(int matchid) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery(
        "SELECT SUM($columnScorerRuns) FROM $tableScorer WHERE $columnScorerMatchId = $matchid");
    int value = result[0]["$columnScorerRuns"];
    return value;
  }

This is my exact code now

Comment: Please make update in the post, it is not easy to read code in comments.

Comment: Would you mind me asking what '0' in `"result[0]["SUM(columnName)"]"` means?

Comment: No I won't mind, `0` means the first item in the `List`. As I said `rawQuery` returns a `List` so what I did was to fetch 1st item (which is at 0th index) in the `List`.

Comment: Got it, thanks. How can I learn all these things? Would I have to learn Sqlite or Sql or mySql? Any tutorials you suggest for this?

Comment: You only need to know `Sqlite` when working for mobile phones, however they all have got similar pattern, you can learn more on internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
double _total;
  void _calcTotal() async {
    var total =
        (await db.getTotal())[0][sum(columname)];
    print(total);
    setState(() {
      _total = total;
    });
  }
```

I added this method inorder to get the total if called in a text widget

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer actually help me but this is what I did from my query to get the total.

```
Future<int> getTotal(String moduleSlug) async{
   var dbClient = await db;
   var queryResult = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(prix_total)  as total from panier where module_slug = ?",[moduleSlug]);
   int total = int.parse(queryResult[0]['total'].toString());
   return total;
  }
```

that function simply return the **total** as **int**. Hope it will help